# MS Access to SharePoint Authentication

Tags: vba, ms-access, connection-string, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to connect my current MS Access forms to SharePoint online. I was able to fetch and feed data without any problem. My only problem is that I want to share the front end to multiple users, but I also need to create a login form to check whether they have access to SharePoint online or not.

Is there a way to add a username/password to the below connection string?

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=2;RetrieveIds=Yes;DATABASE=https://CompanySharepoint.com/Lists/;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

Access will determine if the user is able to login using integrated authentication. This means that users that don't have access to SharePoint won't be able to access the lists.

Depending on your SharePoint config, they might get an error message, or might get a prompt asking them for a username and password. As long as you're cleaning the cache properly, they won't be able to access any data if they have no permission to view the data on SharePoint.